# Selenium Webdriver not executing JavaScript

Tags: javascript, python, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to scrape data from Aliexpress product page. [example.](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/Cosmetic-Brush-Makeup-Blusher-Eye-Shadow-Kabuki-Brushes-Set-Tool-Kit-22pcs/32765190537.html?ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0)

I need [this section.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n75cP.png) (transaction history)

my code:

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium import webdriver
my_url = 'https://www.aliexpress.com/item/Cosmetic-Brush-Makeup-Blusher-Eye-Shadow-Kabuki-Brushes-Set-Tool-Kit-22pcs/32765190537.html?ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0'
chrome_options = Options()  
chrome_options.add_argument("--enable-javascript")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)  
driver.get(my_url)
innerHTML = driver.execute_script('return document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0].innerHTML')
page_html = driver.page_source
```

When i run

> document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0].innerHTML

on the chrome console i get the entire html including the section that i need.
but, the innerHTML object give me the same html as driver.page_source (without the section that i need)
as far as i know this section is not under iFrame.

Some help please :-)

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to look for this specific table.
Using

innerHTML = document.querySelectorAll('table.transaction-feedback-table');

[image]

Will probably find it

Answer (score -1):

The trasactions is generated after the element ID `j-transaction-feedback` is visible, you have to scroll to the element and wait Ajax request finished.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

....
....
driver.get(my_url)

# scroll to the element
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#j-transaction-feedback').location_once_scrolled_into_view

# wait until Ajax finished and render the element
transaction = WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(
    lambda d: d.find_element_by_css_selector('.transaction-feedback-content')
)
total_transaction = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#j-transaction-feedback .text')
page_source = driver.page_source

print('total_transaction: ' + total_transaction.text)
```